# Как сделать чтобы public Transform target; - обновлял поиск?

Tags: unity3d

День добрый. Подскажите такой вопрос, вот код.

```
public Transform target; // объект для вращения по оси Z

void SetRotation()
    {

        Vector2 direction = target.position - transform.position;
        float angle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.y, direction.x) * Mathf.Rad2Deg;
        Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.AngleAxis(angle, Vector3.forward);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, rotation, RotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
```

Указываем таргет и следим за этим объектом. НО. Как сделать, чтобы в случае "потери" таргета, искался новый (желательно по тегу) и снова смотрели на объект

Comment: Что значит "потеря"?

Comment: проверяйте на null и если это так то ищите по тэгу

Comment: Поворюсь. Из кода видно, что мы следим за объектом указанным в target. 
Если, этот таргет (к примеру был назначен вражина у которой закончились хп) умирает\удаляется. Таргет должен обновиться и следить уже на новым targetom

Comment: Как организовать проверку на null? Объясните))

Comment: Поставил вам минус на вопросе. Пожалуйста, смените свой минус на ответе на плюс и отпишитесь мне, чтобы и я снял минус с вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Где то перед вашим кодом поставьте:

```
if(target == null)
{
   target = GameoObject.FindObjectOfTag("tag").transform;
}
```

Comment: А если GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("tag")` не найдет объект с нужным тегом, то `.transform` вызовет ошибку. Поэтому лучше проверять на NULL `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("tag")?.transform`

Comment: @АлександрДаниловский да, вы правы. Я о таком варианте не подумал. Спасибо за дополнение